# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 12 (char 11)

Tags: python, json

I know this looks like some other questions on this site, but this is giving me an error and the other answers don't apply, here is the code that loads the file:

```
with open("Accounts.json") as infile:
    one_char = infile.read(1)
    if one_char:
        accounts = json.load(infile)
```

and the json file:

```
{"ch_1_comp": false, "ch_2_comp": false, "ch_3_comp": false, "ch_4_comp": false, "ch_5_comp": false, "ch_6_comp": false}
```

I'm still getting the error, even though I don't have two data sets, and I can't figure out why

Appreciate the help!

Comment: Why are you reading one character from the beginning of the file? This puts the file pointer at the second character and `json.load` will start decoding starting with `"ch_...`, which is obviously broken JSON to it.

Comment: can you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to see if the file was empty, I had no idea it would have any effect, Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do infile.read(1), it will read the first character, i.e. '{', and put pointer on the double quotes in "ch_1_comp.
Directly load the json, then catch the exception to handle the case if the file is empty.

```
with open("Accounts.json") as infile:
    try:
        accounts = json.load(infile)
    except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
        print("Invalid json")
```